# повторяющийся код

Tags: laravel

в профиле пользователя у меня выводятся предметы, которые открываются при открытии страницы на метод show() страницы, если я редактирую профиль пользователя и страница перезагружается, то пишет что нет метода для вывода предметов, так как на редактирование срабатывает метод edit() и мне приходится дублировать кусок кода для вывода предметов в метод edit. Как можно сделать, чтобы не повторять один и тот же код в разных методах?

```
   public function show()
    {
        //
        $shoolsubject = DB::table('user_subjects')
            ->join('shool_targets', 'shool_targets.id', '=', 'user_subjects.target')
            ->join('school_subjects', 'school_subjects.id', '=', 'user_subjects.shool')
            ->select('shool_targets.name as st', 'school_subjects.name as ss')
            ->where('user_subjects.user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        return view('profile.profile')->with(['profile' => Auth::user(), 'shool' => $shoolsubject->all()]);
    }


public function edit(Request $request)
    {

        /*
         * Вывод добавленных предметов
         */
        $shoolsubject = DB::table('user_subjects')
            ->join('shool_targets', 'shool_targets.id', '=', 'user_subjects.target')
            ->join('school_subjects', 'school_subjects.id', '=', 'user_subjects.shool')
            ->select('shool_targets.name as st', 'school_subjects.name as ss')
            ->where('user_subjects.user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();


        return view('profile.profile')->with(['profile' => Auth::user(), 'shool' => $shoolsubject->all()]);

    }
```

Comment: Вынести в функцию Оо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    // do something

    return $this->show();
}
```